# Does Swarm support syntax highlighting?

Tags: perforce, swarm

Code in code review screen [image]looks pale without syntax highlights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't, but there is an open request at Perforce to add this functionality. You can have your name added to the list of requesters:
http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/3574-feature-request-syntax-highlighting-in-diff-view/

Comment: Syntax highlighting makes code easier to read, so is crucial in any application that displays code. Its omission in Swarm is glaring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, following [Br.Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903510/3797758) to the forum thread it concludes that this was added to the Helix 2022.1 release:

https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-swarm/whats-new-helix-swarm#tab-panel-75495

> ### New Review Page
>
> To help teams work more efficiently, we have rebuilt
> the main page of Helix Swarm. This new and intuitive review page is
> where most developers work. The new review page helps users navigate
> to our most frequently used features so they can quickly collaborate
> to improve code quality. **These features include syntax highlighting**, a new Information panel, a file list, improved markdown support, and
> more! Watch the video to discover all the improvements.